# ggplot for dataframes with differing number of rows

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot three data frames in one plot with differing number of rows. how can i do that in R. I can plot multiple data frames with same number of rows but not otherwise.

if want to some data . here it is

```
 selu            
 47.05770
44.56958
45.83640
54.03050
51.02456
42.87440
47.90603
48.32686
45.52641
50.60718
52.70967
48.82412
50.42237
50.13677
49.09525
53.59709
51.51466
50.36027
50.87862
49.93741


 selm
 41.66651
41.31582
42.03833
39.62356
38.36130
36.48573
42.38672
35.25409
32.86074
45.82076
42.23158
44.24341


sell
42.64645
45.15626
44.93606
46.84997
46.11966
48.22673
46.02169
46.22279
49.61320
46.91678
47.42474
44.53632
41.92584
43.34548
37.15877
40.92660
36.46766
49.43382
50.75494
50.99439
47.70022
44.02300
44.80945
48.05542
46.93999
46.18448
48.04409
46.97649
45.24175
42.72160
43.40993
49.23922
```

I want a plot like the one below but here no.of values are same for both data frame but the data.frames above do not have same number of values. In that case how do i go about producing such a plot

[image]

Comment: Can you give sample data?

Comment: yup i just added . thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any sort of time period for each vector, we are just left to guess, so here ya go...

```
a <- read.table(textConnection("selu            
47.05770
44.56958
45.83640
54.03050
51.02456
42.87440
47.90603
48.32686
45.52641
50.60718
52.70967
48.82412
50.42237
50.13677
49.09525
53.59709
51.51466
50.36027
50.87862
49.93741"), header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

b <- read.table(textConnection("selm
41.66651
41.31582
42.03833
39.62356
38.36130
36.48573
42.38672
35.25409
32.86074
45.82076
42.23158
44.24341"), header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

c <- read.table(textConnection("sell
42.64645
45.15626
44.93606
46.84997
46.11966
48.22673
46.02169
46.22279
49.61320
46.91678
47.42474
44.53632
41.92584
43.34548
37.15877
40.92660
36.46766
49.43382
50.75494
50.99439
47.70022
44.02300
44.80945
48.05542
46.93999
46.18448
48.04409
46.97649
45.24175
42.72160
43.40993
49.23922"), header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

names(a) <- names(b) <- names(c) <- "data"
a$index <- 1:nrow(a)
b$index <- 1:nrow(b)
c$index <- 1:nrow(c)
a$name <- rep("selu", nrow(a))
b$name <- rep("selm", nrow(b))
c$name <- rep("sell", nrow(c))

all <- rbind(a,b,c)

library("ggplot2")
ggplot(all) + geom_line(aes(x=index, y=data, color=name))
```

[image: This is the result]

Comment: thats exactly what i wanted. The data is that of water quality index for upper, lower and middle stream of a river. since there are unequal no.of stations categorize in each of these stream hence the unequal length data. anyways thanks cory . i appreciate.